# Backlit keyboard on Toshiba Satellite P755-S5184 doesn't work in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, laptop, toshiba-satellite

I have the keyboard backlight turned on in bios to timer setting (1 second). When laptop boots the backlight works, but once ubuntu begins to load the backlights turn off.

There is a function key combo that is supposed to turn it on (Fn+Z), hitting that brings up a notification balloon showing the backlit keyboard icon but it is grayed out.

I tried using KeyTouch to try and get the backlight working but my laptop model isn't on the list.

I've read in forums that if you dual boot with windows 7, that doing a complete power cycle (or put to sleep/hibernate) while in windows 7 and restart into Ubuntu that the backlight will work. All information I've seen point to this being an ACPI issue. I've seen scripts to toggle the backlight from within ubuntu, but I don't know how to create/run scripts.

I'm new to Ubuntu, and have been searching the web and can't seem to find any answers that will work for my particular situation. Any information would be MUCH appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have a Toshiba p755-s5265 and I had the same issue a while back. My keyboard backlight now works, and this is what I did:

I **booted up a Windows 7 install dvd**, and at the install screen, I did not proceed but instead **pressed the key on top of my keyboard to light up the keyboard** (pressed it just once). On reboot, the keyboard backlight stayed on past grub and kernel, and is on as I type this. I hope you give it a try.

I'm ready to answer any questions you might have.